Error message for FT in MSM: Exception occured. Root cause : Database
After running FTs for the component paymenttokenserv, I am frequently getting this error which seems to be an MSM issue. Does anybody know how to resolve this error message?
Sample corr id: 32b30274dd7cd

java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception occurred. Root cause : Database "/private/var/folders/bq/gf0_c2dj04x2vnydw8q2s56c0000gq/T/bluefin14234553300163391422" not found, and IFEXISTS=true, so we cant auto-create it [90146-214]

